# Parse method of JsonParser drastically slow down my code

Tags: java, json, gson, inputstream, httpurlconnection

I'm working on project, which should extract data from JSON files(contains information about polish deputies) and do a few calculations just using these data.

Code is executing properly, but one method drastically slows down everything.
 Im not the best in describing, so let's show my Jsonreader class
[Gist link](https://gist.github.com/mwoss/f26b96f771f6976f3dc8c5ccc0614ae6)
(Method was used in 17th,43th,50th line)
Code looks kinda messy, but it works fine, excluding fragments using jsonparser.parse method. It tooks unacceptable ~2sec per envoy. I have to change that few lines, but I don't know how.
I was thinking about prescribing json file to map object and then working on it, but im not sure if it is a good option.
(Sorry for my poor grammar)

Comment: Are you *sure* it is the `parse()` method that is slow, and not the retrieving of the JSON text from HTTPS server using `getContent()` that is slow?

Comment: @Andreas It's possible that is getContent() method i'm not 100% sure, because i was checking times for every line of my code not every method. How should I test it? And if it's that method, how can i speed it up?

Comment: Only way to speed it up would be to use multiple threads.

Comment: @Andreas Is it possible to do by such begginers as I am?

Comment: I can't answer that. Only you can.

Comment: @Andreas One more question. How can i check if problem lies in taht getContent method?

Answer (score 1):

> How can i check if problem lies in taht getContent method?

You can prove it indirectly: just check your service API performance in your web browser network debugger tab, or measure the time for simple wget like `time wget YOUR_URL`.

I agree with [Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5221149/andreas) having doubt that the `parse` method is the root of the evil. Actually it's not. If you look at your gist closer, you can see that the `parse` method accepts a delegated reader that actually uses the underlying input stream that's "connected" with the remote host. I/O usually are very time-consuming operations, especially networking. Also, establishing an HTTP connection is an expensive thing here.
At my machine I've ended up with the following  average timing:

- making HTTP requests: ~1.50..2.00s at the very first request, and 0.50..1.00s for the consecutive ones;
- reading data: ~0.80s (either dumb reading until the end, or JSON parsing -- does not really matter, Gson is really very fast; also you can profile the performance even in your browser with a network debugger or `time wget URL` if you use a Unix terminal).

Another point suggested by Andreas is use of multiple threads in order to run independent tasks in parallel. This can speed the things up, but it won't make super change to you since your service access is not that fast, unfortunately.

```
Executing SingleThreadedDemo...
Executing SingleThreadedDemo took 1063935ms         = ~17:43
Executing MultiThreadedDemo...
Executing MultiThreadedDemo took 353044ms           = ~5:53
```

Running the demo later gave the following results (approximately 3 times faster, no idea what's the real cause of the previous slowdown)

```
Executing SingleThreadedDemo...
Executing SingleThreadedDemo took 382249ms          = ~6:22
Executing MultiThreadedDemo...
Executing MultiThreadedDemo took 130502ms           = ~2:11
Executing MultiThreadedDemo...
Executing MultiThreadedDemo took 110119ms           = ~1:50
```

#### AbstractDemo.java

The following class violates some good OOP design concepts, but in order not to bloat the total number of classes, let its stuff just be here.

```java
abstract class AbstractDemo
        implements Callable<List<EnvoyData>> {

    // Gson is thread-safe
    private static final Gson gson = new Gson();

    // JsonParser is thread-safe: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-gson/u6hq2OVpszc
    private static final JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();

    interface IPointsAndYearbooksConsumer {

        void acceptPointsAndYearbooks(SerializedDataPoints points, SerializedDataYears yearbooks);

    }

    interface ITripsConsumer {

        void acceptTrips(SerializedDataTrips trips);

    }

    AbstractDemo() {
    }

    protected abstract List<EnvoyData> doCall()
            throws Exception;

    // This implementation measures time (in milliseconds) taken for each demo call
    @Override
    public final List<EnvoyData> call()
            throws Exception {
        final String name = getClass().getSimpleName();
        final long start = currentTimeMillis();
        try {
            out.printf("Executing %s...\n", name);
            final List<EnvoyData> result = doCall();
            out.printf("Executing %s took %dms\n", name, currentTimeMillis() - start);
            return result;
        } catch ( final Exception ex ) {
            err.printf("Executing %s took %dms\n", name, currentTimeMillis() - start);
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    // This is a generic method that encapsulates generic pagination and lets you to iterate over the service pages in for-each style manner 
    static Iterable<JsonElement> jsonRequestsAt(final URL startUrl, final Function<? super JsonObject, URL> nextLinkExtrator, final JsonParser jsonParser) {
        return () -> new Iterator<JsonElement>() {
            private URL nextUrl = startUrl;

            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                return nextUrl != null;
            }

            @Override
            public JsonElement next() {
                if ( nextUrl == null ) {
                    throw new NoSuchElementException();
                }
                try ( final Reader reader = readFrom(nextUrl) ) {
                    final JsonElement root = jsonParser.parse(reader);
                    nextUrl = nextLinkExtrator.apply(root.getAsJsonObject());
                    return root;
                } catch ( final IOException ex ) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(ex);
                }
            }
        };
    }

    // Just a helper method to iterate over the start response
    static Iterable<JsonElement> getAfterwords()
            throws MalformedURLException {
        return jsonRequestsAt(
                afterwordsUrl(),
                root -> {
                    try {
                        final JsonElement next = root.get("Links").getAsJsonObject().get("next");
                        return next != null ? new URL(next.getAsString()) : null;
                    } catch ( final MalformedURLException ex ) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
                    }
                },
                jsonParser
        );
    }

    // Just extract points and yearbooks.
    // You can return a custom data holder class, but this one uses consuming-style passing the results via its parameter consumer
    static void extractPointsAndYearbooks(final Reader reader, final IPointsAndYearbooksConsumer consumer) {
        final JsonObject expensesJsonObject = jsonParser.parse(reader)
                .getAsJsonObject()
                .get("layers")
                .getAsJsonObject()
                .get("wydatki")
                .getAsJsonObject();
        final SerializedDataPoints points = gson.fromJson(expensesJsonObject.get("punkty").getAsJsonArray(), SerializedDataPoints.class);
        final SerializedDataYears yearbooks = gson.fromJson(expensesJsonObject.get("roczniki").getAsJsonArray(), SerializedDataYears.class);
        consumer.acceptPointsAndYearbooks(points, yearbooks);
    }

    // The same as above but for another type of response
    static void extractTrips(final Reader reader, final ITripsConsumer consumer) {
        final JsonElement tripsJsonElement = jsonParser.parse(reader)
                .getAsJsonObject()
                .get("layers")
                .getAsJsonObject()
                .get("wyjazdy");
        final SerializedDataTrips trips = tripsJsonElement.isJsonArray()
                ? gson.fromJson(tripsJsonElement.getAsJsonArray(), SerializedDataTrips.class)
                : null;
        consumer.acceptTrips(trips);
    }

    // It might be a constant field, but the next methods are dynamic (parameter-dependent), so let them all be similar
    // Checked exceptions are not that evil, and let the call-site decide what to do with them
    static URL afterwordsUrl()
            throws MalformedURLException {
        return new URL("https://api-v3.mojepanstwo.pl/dane/poslowie.json");
    }

    // The same as above
    static URL afterwordsUrl(final int page)
            throws MalformedURLException {
        return new URL("https://api-v3.mojepanstwo.pl/dane/poslowie.json?_type=objects&page=" + page);
    }

    // The same as above
    static URL tripsUrl(final int envoyId)
            throws MalformedURLException {
        return new URL("https://api-v3.mojepanstwo.pl/dane/poslowie/" + envoyId + ".json?layers[]=wyjazdy");
    }

    // The same as above
    static URL expensesUrl(final int envoyId)
            throws MalformedURLException {
        return new URL("https://api-v3.mojepanstwo.pl/dane/poslowie/" + envoyId + ".json?layers[]=wydatki");
    }

    // Since jsonParser is encapsulated
    static JsonElement parseJsonElement(final Reader reader) {
        return jsonParser.parse(reader);
    }

    // A helper method to return a reader for the given URL
    static Reader readFrom(final URL url)
            throws IOException {
        final HttpURLConnection request = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        request.connect();
        return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((InputStream) request.getContent()));
    }

    // Waits for all futures used in multi-threaded demo
    // Not sure how good this method is since I'm not an expert in concurrent programming unfortunately
    static void waitForAllFutures(final Iterable<? extends Future<?>> futures)
            throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        final Iterator<? extends Future<?>> iterator = futures.iterator();
        while ( iterator.hasNext() ) {
            final Future<?> future = iterator.next();
            future.get();
            iterator.remove();
        }
    }

}
```

#### SingleThreadedDemo.java

The simplest demo. Entire data pulling is executed in a single thread, so it tends to be the slowest demo here. This one is totally thread-safe having no fields and can be declared as a singleton.

```java
final class SingleThreadedDemo
        extends AbstractDemo {

    private static final Callable<List<EnvoyData>> singleThreadedDemo = new SingleThreadedDemo();

    private SingleThreadedDemo() {
    }

    static Callable<List<EnvoyData>> getSingleThreadedDemo() {
        return singleThreadedDemo;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<EnvoyData> doCall()
            throws IOException {
        final List<EnvoyData> envoys = new ArrayList<>();
        for ( final JsonElement afterwordJsonElement : getAfterwords() ) {
            final JsonArray dataObjectArray = afterwordJsonElement.getAsJsonObject().get("Dataobject").getAsJsonArray();
            for ( final JsonElement dataObjectElement : (Iterable<JsonElement>) dataObjectArray::iterator ) {
                final int envoyId = dataObjectElement.getAsJsonObject().get("id").getAsInt();
                try ( final Reader expensesReader = readFrom(expensesUrl(envoyId)) ) {
                    extractPointsAndYearbooks(expensesReader, (points, yearbooks) -> {
                        // ... consume points and yearbooks here
                    });
                }
                try ( final Reader tripsReader = readFrom(tripsUrl(envoyId)) ) {
                    extractTrips(tripsReader, trips -> {
                        // ... consume trips here
                    });
                }
            }
        }
        return envoys;
    }

}
```

#### MultiThreadedDemo.java

Unfortunately I'm really very weak in Java concurrency, and probably these multi-threaded demos can be improved dramatically. This semi-multi-threaded demo that uses both approaches:

- one thread for iterating over pages;
- multiple threads to grab points, yearbooks, and trips data.

Also note that this demo (and another multi-threaded one below) is not fail-safe: if anything throws an exception in a submitted task, the executor service background thread won't terminate properly.
Thus you might want to make it fail-safe and robust yourself.

```java
final class MultiThreadedDemo
        extends AbstractDemo {

    private final ExecutorService executorService;

    private MultiThreadedDemo(final ExecutorService executorService) {
        this.executorService = executorService;
    }

    static Callable<List<EnvoyData>> getMultiThreadedDemo(final ExecutorService executorService) {
        return new MultiThreadedDemo(executorService);
    }

    @Override
    protected List<EnvoyData> doCall()
            throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, MalformedURLException {
        final List<EnvoyData> envoys = synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
        final Collection<Future<?>> futures = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
        for ( final JsonElement afterwordJsonElement : getAfterwords() ) {
            final JsonArray dataObjectArray = afterwordJsonElement.getAsJsonObject().get("Dataobject").getAsJsonArray();
            for ( final JsonElement dataObjectElement : (Iterable<JsonElement>) dataObjectArray::iterator ) {
                final int envoyId = dataObjectElement.getAsJsonObject().get("id").getAsJsonPrimitive().getAsInt();
                submitExtractPointsAndYearbooks(futures, envoyId);
                submitExtractTrips(futures, envoyId);
            }
        }
        waitForAllFutures(futures);
        return envoys;
    }

    private void submitExtractPointsAndYearbooks(final Collection<? super Future<?>> futures, final int envoyId) {
        futures.add(executorService.submit(() -> {
            try ( final Reader expensesReader = readFrom(expensesUrl(envoyId)) ) {
                extractPointsAndYearbooks(expensesReader, (points, yearbooks) -> {
                    // ... consume points and yearbooks here
                });
                return null;
            }
        }));
    }

    private void submitExtractTrips(final Collection<? super Future<?>> futures, final int envoyId) {
        futures.add(executorService.submit(() -> {
            try ( final Reader tripsReader = readFrom(tripsUrl(envoyId)) ) {
                extractTrips(tripsReader, trips -> {
                    // ... consume trips here
                });
                return null;
            }
        }));
    }

}
```

#### MultiThreadedEstimatedPagesDemo.java

This one is somewhat more enhanced version of the previous demo. But this demo submits executor service tasks for iterating over the service pages. To achieve it, it's necessary to detect the number of pages beforehand. And having the number of pages lets to make `https://...poslowie.json?...page=...` URLs processing parallel. Note that if there are more than 1 page found, the next iteration starts from the 2nd page, not making a duplicate request.

```java
final class MultiThreadedEstimatedPagesDemo
        extends AbstractDemo {

    private final ExecutorService executorService;

    private MultiThreadedEstimatedPagesDemo(final ExecutorService executorService) {
        this.executorService = executorService;
    }

    static Callable<List<EnvoyData>> getMultiThreadedEstimatedPagesDemo(final ExecutorService executorService) {
        return new MultiThreadedEstimatedPagesDemo(executorService);
    }

    @Override
    protected List<EnvoyData> doCall()
            throws IOException, JsonIOException, JsonSyntaxException, InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        final List<EnvoyData> envoys = synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
        final JsonObject page1RootJsonObject;
        final int totalPages;
        try ( final Reader page1Reader = readFrom(afterwordsUrl()) ) {
            page1RootJsonObject = parseJsonElement(page1Reader).getAsJsonObject();
            totalPages = estimateTotalPages(page1RootJsonObject);
        }
        final Collection<Future<?>> futures = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
        futures.add(executorService.submit(() -> {
            final JsonArray dataObjectArray = page1RootJsonObject.getAsJsonObject().get("Dataobject").getAsJsonArray();
            for ( final JsonElement dataObjectElement : (Iterable<JsonElement>) dataObjectArray::iterator ) {
                final int envoyId = dataObjectElement.getAsJsonObject().get("id").getAsInt();
                submitExtractPointsAndYearbooks(futures, envoyId);
                submitExtractTrips(futures, envoyId);
            }
            return null;
        }));
        for ( int page = 2; page <= totalPages; page++ ) {
            final int finalPage = page;
            futures.add(executorService.submit(() -> {
                try ( final Reader reader = readFrom(afterwordsUrl(finalPage)) ) {
                    final JsonElement afterwordJsonElement = parseJsonElement(reader);
                    final JsonArray dataObjectArray = afterwordJsonElement.getAsJsonObject().get("Dataobject").getAsJsonArray();
                    for ( final JsonElement dataObjectElement : (Iterable<JsonElement>) dataObjectArray::iterator ) {
                        final int envoyId = dataObjectElement.getAsJsonObject().get("id").getAsInt();
                        submitExtractPointsAndYearbooks(futures, envoyId);
                        submitExtractTrips(futures, envoyId);
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }));
        }
        waitForAllFutures(futures);
        return envoys;
    }

    private static int estimateTotalPages(final JsonObject rootJsonObject) {
        final int elementsPerPage = rootJsonObject.get("Dataobject").getAsJsonArray().size();
        final int totalElements = rootJsonObject.get("Count").getAsInt();
        return (int) ceil((double) totalElements / elementsPerPage);
    }

    private void submitExtractPointsAndYearbooks(final Collection<? super Future<?>> futures, final int envoyId) {
        futures.add(executorService.submit(() -> {
            try ( final Reader expensesReader = readFrom(expensesUrl(envoyId)) ) {
                extractPointsAndYearbooks(expensesReader, (points, yearbooks) -> {
                    // ... consume points and yearbooks here
                });
                return null;
            }
        }));
    }

    private void submitExtractTrips(final Collection<? super Future<?>> futures, final int envoyId) {
        futures.add(executorService.submit(() -> {
            try ( final Reader tripsReader = readFrom(tripsUrl(envoyId)) ) {
                extractTrips(tripsReader, trips -> {
                    // ... consume trips here
                });
                return null;
            }
        }));
    }

}
```

#### Test.java

And the demo itself:

```java
public final class Test {

    private Test() {
    }

    public static void main(final String... args)
            throws Exception {
        runSingleThreadedDemo();
        runMultiThreadedDemo();
        runMultiThreadedEstimatedPagesDemo();
    }

    private static void runSingleThreadedDemo()
            throws Exception {
        final Callable<?> singleThreadedDemo = getSingleThreadedDemo();
        singleThreadedDemo.call();
    }

    private static void runMultiThreadedDemo()
            throws Exception {
        final ExecutorService executorService = newFixedThreadPool(getRuntime().availableProcessors());
        final Callable<?> demo = getMultiThreadedDemo(executorService);
        demo.call();
        executorService.shutdown();
    }

    private static void runMultiThreadedEstimatedPagesDemo()
            throws Exception {
        final ExecutorService executorService = newFixedThreadPool(getRuntime().availableProcessors());
        final Callable<?> demo = getMultiThreadedEstimatedPagesDemo(executorService);
        demo.call();
        executorService.shutdown();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you! Your post helps me a lot.:)